# Объяснение некоторых возможностей библиотеке filesystem

Tags: c++, файловая-система

сделал программу, которая по 2 параметрам с командой строки, а именно (Адрес директории и ключевое слово) ищет в директории текстовые файлы, содержащие ключевое слово. Код полностью мой за исключением способа нахождения названия файлов в нужном адресе, дабы потом их открывать и искать ключевое слово. К тем моментам которые мне непонятны, я добавил комментарии. Очень прошу вас проверить правильно ли я пониманию, как это работает и по возможности исправить как будет правильнее. (Второй комментарий объяснять не надо, добавил, чтобы вам было понятнее разобраться, что такое p), очень надеюсь на вашу помощь

```
namespace fs = experimental::filesystem; // создаем пространство имен fs, подключаем из области видимости experimental работу с файловой системы, взятой из библиотеки filesystem





void ShowListFile(string p,string word) // в p хранится адрес директории, например: C:\\test, word - ключевое слово, которое мы ищем в текстовых файлов
{
    bool sh = false;
    cout << "Список удовлетворяющих текстовых файлов:" << endl;
    for (auto i = fs::directory_iterator(p); i != fs::directory_iterator(); i++) // здесь мы используем структутуру считывания fs, которая ищет работает с каждым файлом в папке до тех пор, пока эти файлы не закончатся, идентификатор auto служит для определения типа переменной i, но если не использовать auto, какой может быть тип переменной i?
    {
        if (!fs::is_directory(i->path())) // если указатель на структуру нашего текущего файла не является другой директоторией, то
        {
            if (i->path().extension() == ".txt") // если указатель на структуру нашего текущего файла имеет формат txt, то
            {
                string find;
                find = p + "\\";
                find += i->path().filename().string();
                ifstream fin(find);
                string wr;
                string str1;
                string str2;
                str2 = word;
                while (getline(fin, wr))
                {
                    for (int l = 0; l < wr.length(); l++)
                        if (wr[l] != ' ' && l != wr.length())
                            str1 = str1 + wr[l];
                        else if (wr[l] == ' ' || l == wr.length())
                        {
                            if(str1 == str2)
                            {
                                cout << i->path().filename().string() << endl;
                                sh = true;
                                fin.close();
                                break;
                            }
                            str1 = "";
                        }
                }

                fin.close();
            }

        }
        else
            continue;
    }
    if (!sh)
    {
        cout << "пусто" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Вместо написания длинных комментариев, лучше сразу давать переменным толковые имена, например `folder_path` вместо `p`. Тип `i` - это тип, по которым можно итерировать `directory_iterator`, например `std::filesystem::directory_entry const &`.

Comment: А чем по сути является directory_iterator я описал верно? В особенности namespace fs = experimental::filesystem;

Comment: Нет, `namespace fs = experimental::filesystem;` объявляет алиас `fs` (то бишь еще одно имя для обращения) для пространства имен `::std::experimental::filesystem`, а не создает новых пространств имен

Comment: Следующие комментарии правильно описал? Я еще опытным путем i->path().filename().string() менял на i->path().filename() и выводилось тоже самое, в чем разница не понял (

Comment: Почитайте сначала [справку по этим вызовам](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path), там все это описывается.

Comment: А я это читал, только на другом вроде сайте, благодаря этому я сделал, так, что оно ищет только текстовые файлы, if (i->path().extension() == ".txt") - этого не было в способе нахождения файлов в директориях.  Просто проблема еще в том, что на английском языке, это затрудняет понятие многих моментов, поэтому и решил спросить здесь (